# Google Analytics tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, browser-history

I'd like to remove the Google Analytics URL tracking code from the browser bar so that when a user copy / pastes the URL to share they don't bring along all the tracking data with them, which is both useless and able to skew the data down the road.

So I'm using history.js to run replaceState to basically get rid of the tracking data from the URL after a brief pause.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    if( window.location.search.indexOf( "utm_campaign" ) >= 1 ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, document.title, window.location.pathname);
    }
}, 1000 );
</script>
```

Does anyone see any possible complications or problems with such a method?

Comment: I can see a huge problem. It's only for HTML5 browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method

Comment: @MikeRobinson : I added the pause just in-case the GA ansynchronous tracker was still pulling information out of the URL when I run it.

Comment: @MathieuImbert : That's completely true, but I'd rather have it work for "some and future" browsers rather then none at all. It's not mission critical, but it is nice to have.

Comment: @stevecomrie as long as you are ready to drop Internet Explorer from this feature, the only possible drawback is breaking the browser back button. The user will need to click twice (tested in chrome, it might be different in other browsers) on the back button to go back to the previous page.

Comment: @MathieuImbert I'm not really "dropping" support for IE, it's just not something that is possible with IE and I can live with that. I'm interested in providing the best solution with the least problems and frankly that means ignoring IE.

Also, I've tested it on Chrome and I'm not seeing the double-back issue that you mentioned (on Chrome or on any other browser). replaceState() does not (should not) introduce another state like it would if you were using pushState(). Can you verify that you're using history.js and that this is still happening for you.

Comment: @stevecomrie Of course I wasn't saying that you won't support IE, I was only referring to this specific functionality. As for the back button I guess I was mistaken, I tested again and didn't notice anything strange happening.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that you might have is that Google Analytics might not have been fully loaded by the time that your timeout code runs.

With the Google Analytics tracker, there is an API that lets a function be queued after the GA data has been sent off to Google.

You can do something like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(function() {
  var newPath = location.pathname + location.search.replace(/[?&]utm_[^?&]+/g, "").replace(/^&/, "?") + location.hash;
  if (history.replaceState) history.replaceState(null, '', newPath);
});

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Notice line 4, where a function is pushed to the _gaq object.

This function will replace the URL straight after the GA request has been sent.